# Remove object from RealmList based on primary key

Tags: android, realm

How can i remove single object from Realm Result based on primary key of objects stored in Realm. Below is my Realm Model

```
open class ParentModel : RealmObject(){
@Required
@PrimaryKey
var uid : String ?= null

var realmRequest : RealmList<RealmRequests> ?= null
```

}

Now i wanna remove object from `RealmList` based on the primary key of RealmRequest. How can i do that . Tell me please.

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmResults.html#clear--

Comment: clear() will delete all objects from Realm Result. I don't wanna delete all of them. Just to delete single object based on primary key.

Comment: public boolean remove(Object object)

Comment: I have primary key of that object . i cannot use remove() as it take object.

Comment: Please define if by "delete" you mean "delete from the Realm", or you mean "remove from RealmList" thank you

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I mean "remove From RealmList" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
val parentModel = realm.where<ParentModel>().equalTo("uid", uid).findFirst()
val request = realm.where<RealmRequests>().equalTo("id", id).findFirst()
if(parentModel != null && request != null) {
    parentModel.realmRequest?.remove(request)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this method. Set Class to Class which will be search to delete.

```
  public void deleteClass(Int id) {
            realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> realm.where(Class.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst().deleteFromRealm());
        }
```